# Entitystate.Modified mvc3 reference object not saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a problem saving my trainer object.
Everything got saved exept for the trainer.
I looked at the object training and all properties are filled in. (also the properties of location and trainer)
I do not get an error but the trainer object is not being saved.

Here is my code:

```
   Context db=new Context();

    public void modifieTraining(Training training)
    {
        db.Entry(training.Location).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(training.Trainer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(training).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

It's the only object that i get like so:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("trainer", new SelectList(ViewBag.Trainer, "TrainerId", "Firstname"), "Selecteer een trainer")
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location.Address)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Location.City)
  ...
```

later in my controller:

```
  public ActionResult EditTraining(int id, Training training, string trainer)
    {
            if (trainer != null && trainer!="Selecteer een trainer" )
            {
                training.Trainer = repository.getTrainer(Convert.ToInt32(trainer));
            }
            repository.modifieTraining(training);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
```

---

for some strange reason when i rebooted the machine everything went fine.
But when I open sql server management studio. It still shows me a NULL value.
But when I execute the get method the right value shows up.

Could it be because the field is nullable?

Comment: I've never seen examples of individual properties being marked as modified although it does sound like a reasonable thing to do.  2 things though: 1. `db.Entry(training.State) = EntityState.Modified;` I take it you already have `.State` in there.  2. Have you tried: `db.Entry(training).State = EntityState.Modified;` rather than setting modified for each individual property?

Comment: Try db.Attach(training.Trainer). Guess it's not attached to the context.

Comment: Sorry, the ".State" was a typo of me. In my code it's typed correctly.
I will correct it
I looked at the context and saw it was already attached.
I tryed detach and attach again but didn't help

Comment: You get the training from the repository but do not modify any of its properties. You just say its _state_ is Modified.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me for the first answer.
But I found the problem now.
The problem was that I wasn't realy modifying anything.
I just added a trainer to the object but the trainerobject itself was not modified so nothing changed.

model was like this:

```
  public class Training
  {
    [Key]
    public int TrainingId { get; set; }

    public Trainer Trainer{get; set;}
    ....
  }
```

Added in model:

```
  public int? TrainerId{get; set;}
```

controller:

```
  public ActionResult EditTraining(int id, Training training, string trainer)
  {
        if (trainer != null && trainer!="Selecteer een trainer" )
        {
            training.Trainer = repository.getTrainer(Convert.ToInt32(trainer));
            trainingDetail.TrainerId = trainingDetail.Trainer.TrainerId;
         }
         repository.modifieTraining(training);
  }
```

Thanks for all the help and sorry for the stupid answer.